# Make flex section and general sections same width

Tags: html, css

I have three sections A, B and C. All sections have max-width of 900px, but third section is shorter than the other twos: https://codepen.io/Boryamba/pen/oNgjoOe

Also, i want h2 element in section C to be above div's text but because this section is flex h2 stays on the same line as divs: https://codepen.io/Boryamba/pen/bGNVYyZ

Questions: how do i make all three sections same width? Is it possible to make h2 element in section C to be above divs using flexbox?

```css
.section-head {
    padding-bottom: 1em;
}

#section-a {
    padding         : 1.5em;
    background-color: rgba(0, 139, 139, 0.4);
    color           : #fff;
    text-align      : center;
    max-width       : 900px;
    margin          : 0 auto;
}

#section-b {
    padding         : 1.5em;
    background-color: rgba(139, 139, 139, 0.4);
    color           : #000;
    text-align      : center;
    max-width       : 900px;
    margin          : 0 auto;
}

#section-c {
    display: flex;
    max-width: 900px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#section-c .box1, #section-c .box3 {
    background-color: rgba(0, 139, 139, 0.4);
    color: whitesmoke;
    padding: 5px 20px;
}

#section-c .box2 {
    padding: 5px 20px;
    background-color: rgba(139, 139, 139, 0.4);
    color: #000;
}
```

```html
<section id="section-a">
    <h2 class="section-head">Section A</h2>
    <p>
        Lorem ipsum...
    </p>
</section>
<section id="section-b">
    <h2 class="section-head">Section B</h2>
    <p>
        Lorem ipsum...
    </p>
</section>
<section id="section-c">
    <div class="box1">Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloremque nemo adipisci quibusdam
        perferendis provident impedit?</div>
    <div class="box2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Omnis sed velit maiores sequi quibusdam
        autem.</div>
    <div class="box3">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Cum, animi earum natus mollitia ex magni!
    </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make all divs the same width remove the left and right padding for section A and B, like this:

```
#section-a {
    padding         : 1.5em 0;
    background-color: rgba(0, 139, 139, 0.4);
    color           : #fff;
    text-align      : center;
    max-width       : 900px;
    margin          : 0 auto;
}

#section-b {
    padding         : 1.5em 0;
    background-color: rgba(139, 139, 139, 0.4);
    color           : #000;
    text-align      : center;
    max-width       : 900px;
    margin          : 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked. I just realised i could add box-sizing: border-box to the whole page to solve the issue.

Comment: Yes, that is also another solution